# HA Proxy TCP Content Rejection

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, tcpip

I am looking for an option or a work around where I can accept or reject the TCP Content based on the the size of a file which is getting uploaded This settings is required on TCP IP layer only also we have tried options like req_len(not working), as well as src_kbytes_in(works fine only after first request is shared) if any one can help me on this I will be of greatful
.

Comment: I do not have the answer to your question, however in general you should specify the operating system and version of the software you are using and if you have updated it to the most current version of the software.

Comment: Ubuntu Linux / haproxy 2.3

Answer (score 0):

TCP layer doesn't knows nothing about files and their sizes. It has nothing to do with it. TCP is a transport layer 4, while the files are transferred using application layer 7 (i.e. HTTP/HTTPS). So your question are quite meaningless due to this.

Besides afaik haproxy doesn't knows anything about files either. It works like a proxy and doesn't handles file uploads. It's the backend server which should worry about upload files limits. If you use HTTP(S) POST standard file uploads you should refer to your webserver documentation on how to limit HTTP(S) maximum upload size.

EDIT: also, take a look at this answer regarding haproxy doesn't handles upload limits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820640/increase-the-upload-limit-of-haproxy

Comment: Thanks for reaching out and replying - I understand whatever is mentioned here seems to be irrelevant however i should not have use word file - basically I will say that I need to reject ongoing TCP/IP Request base on the total bytes this TCP request have received - I am able to do this using stick table but works only fine when the bytes gets accumulate like flooding.